# Bubble down implementation for min-heap

Tags: data-structures, heaps, priority-queues

While going through `bubble_down` implementation for min-heap in The Algorithm Design Manual By Steven Skiena, since routine `pq_young_child` gives the index for youngest child which can be replaced with the parent I feel the lines 10 - 13 are useless or maybe I am not able to identify the cases it handles. Here is the implementation given in the book.

```
bubble_down(priority_queue *q, int p)
{
    int c;                /* child index */
    int i;                /* counter */
    int min_index;        /* index of lightest child */

    c = pq_young_child(p);
    min_index = p; 

    for (i=0; i<=1; i++)
        if ((c+i) <= q->n) {
            if (q->q[min_index] > q->q[c+i]) min_index = c+i;
        }

    if (min_index != p) {
        pq_swap(q,p,min_index);
        bubble_down(q, min_index);
    }
}
```

Do these lines handle any specific corner cases? I can't come up with the test cases which would fail if I remove these 4 lines.

Comment: The "Edit:" is not needed, since the revision history is available. At first your question seems a bit off-topic to me, as this are implementation details and debugging provided that some lines are deleted. Lines are not commented (to show which lines you refer to, small nitpick, but eases reading). It would be nice to find counterexample (but I think that such search is not in the scope of this site), try to write your own implementation or perform "assymptotically satisfactory" with hypothesis that runtime differs (the larger the data the more probable the result).

Comment: Which lines are you asking about?  The `if` statement?  Or the `for` loop?  It might be hard to know how to answer the question without knowing what `pq_young_child()` and `pq_swap()` do.  What does "youngest child" mean?  Have you tried to prove the code correct either with or without those lines?